# How to use {{ }} inside Angular filters while inside nested ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use {{ }} inside the angular "filter" filter, while inside a nest ng-repeat. Take for example the following relationship:

```
var categories = [
    {"title":"land"},
    {"title":"sea"},
    {"title":"air"}
];

var vehicles = [
    {"name":"car", "class":"land"},
    {"name":"boat", "class":"sea"},
    {"name":"helicopter", "class":"air"}
];
```

And my HTML:

```
   <div ng-repeat='cat in categories'>
      <table ng-repeat="v in vehicles | filter: {class: {{cat.title}} }">
        <tr>{{v.name}}</tr>
      </table>
   </div>
```

How can I dynamically filter my table to show the vehicle by the filtered class?

Comment: You don't need `{{ }}` in the `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: Just skip them .... <table ng-repeat="v in vehicles | filter: {class: cat.title }">

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user @HaukurHaf for the answer! Simply omit the {{ }}. Quick and simple:

```
<table ng-repeat='v in vehicles | filter: {class: cat.title}">
```